# WMB: In ESQL, is it possible to connect to a datasource defined as a JDBCProvider configurable service in lieu of ODBC DSN?

Tags: jdbc, messagebroker, embedded-sql

I'm inheriting an existing WMB flow that is ESQL-centric (Compute nodes) that accesses its database via an ODBC DSN.  I'd prefer to use a configurable service for database access in lieu of an ODBC DSN, which is what I use with Java-centric flows (JavaCompute nodes).

Is it possible to configure a Compute node to talk to a db via a configurable service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need to call a Java class from the ESQL.

See [Connecting to an application database using JDBC](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21404861)